# Ecto update_all example

Tags: orm, sql-update, elixir, ecto

I would like to update all fields that match query

```
MyModel  
|> where([m], m.state == "begin") 
|> update([set: %{state: "commit"}]) 
|> Repo.update_all()
```

But I get:

```
 malformed update `[set: %{state: "commit"}]` in query expression, expected a keyword list with set/push/pop as keys with field-value pairs as values
```

What I do wrong here?

Comment: I think `%{state: "commit"}` should be a keyword list, not a map. So: `update(set: [state: "commit"])` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `update` function does but can you try passing in directly to `Repo.update_all()`

```
Repo.update_all(from(m in MyModel, where: m.state == "begin", update: [set: [%{state: "commit"}]))
```